# Reorder a list so that the total consecutive difference between two elements is the smallest possible

Tags: python, list, reorderlist

Say we have a list. How can we reorder it so that the total difference between two consecutive elements is the smallest possible?
For example, list = [7, 4, 2, 6].
The differences between two consecutive elements are 3,2,4
Therefore, the total difference is 9.
We can rearrange it to become [2, 4, 6, 7] (not sorting)
The differences between two consecutive elements are 2,2,1
Therefore, the total difference is 5.

I already created a function to calculate the total difference of a list.

```
def total_diff(test_list):
    t = 0
    for i in range(1, len(test_list)):
        t += test_list[i] - test_list[i-1]
    return t
```

What should I do next?

Comment: Surely this amounts to simply sorting the list? Anything unsorted will simply add greater variation. A better problem might be to make the total variation as large as possible.

Comment: I tried sorting, but it didn't pass the full test

Comment: can you share the test case?

Comment: What do you mean by "not sorting"? `[2, 4, 6, 7]` *is* sorted.

Comment: I think it's easy to mathematically prove that moving an element from the sorted list will augment the total difference!

Comment: @Đỗ Quốc Khánh, maybe you had better show the code where you "tried sorting". Maybe the try wasn't successful.

Comment: Your function isn't computing the absolute values of the differences, like your example implies it should be.

Comment: `list[1] - list[0]` is `-3`, not `3`.

Comment: Do you actually need to reorder the list? Or do you just need to find the smallest possible diff sum?

Answer (score 1):

Your `total_diff` function needs to compute the sum of the *aboslute values* of the differences:

```
def total_diff(test_list):
    t = 0
    for i in range(1, len(test_list)):
        t += abs(test_list[i] - test_list[i-1])
    return t
```

Otherwise, the differences are a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) whose sum depends only on the first and last elements of the list.

```
TD(L) = (L[1] - L[0]) + (L[2] - L[1]) + (L[3] - L[2]) + ... + (L[n-1] - L[n-2])
      = -L[0] + (L[1] - L[1]) + (L[2] - L[2]) + ... + (L[n-1] - L[n-2])
      = -L[0] + L[n-1]
```